# Why does the Nash-Kuiper theorem imply that Riemannian manifolds can be isometrically embedded into arbitrarly small neighborhoods of Euclidean space?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

There's a sentence in the Wikipedia page for the [Nash-Kuiper theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorems#Nash%E2%80%93Kuiper_theorem_(C1_embedding_theorem)) that I don't understand:

> In particular, as follows from the Whitney embedding theorem, any $$-dimensional Riemannian manifold admits an isometric $\mathcal{C}^1$-embedding into an *arbitrarily small neighborhood* in $2m$-dimensional Euclidean space.

This claim doesn't seem to follow from either the strong or the weak version of the [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) (WET). The strong version of the WET only applies to embeddings into all of $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$, not into small neighborhoods of $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$. And the weak version only applies to embeddings into manifolds of dimension greater than $2m$. So neither version seems to apply here.

Is the quoted claim above using the strong or the weak version of the WET, and how?

Comment: How does anything about a Riemannian metric follow from any version of Whitney?

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe that they are using the Whitney embedding theorem to establish the existence of an embedding of the manifold's *smooth* structure into either $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ or some subset of that space (that's my question), and then they are using the Nash-Kuiper theorem to find another arbitrarily close by *isometric* embedding that preserves the Riemannian metric structure as well.

Comment: I concur, but that is a horribly written and very misleading sentence on Wiki. It follows from Nash-Kuiper (the strong result) after using Whitney (the easy result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Whitney theorem you have an embeding, say $\phi_0$. Shrink it in the form $\phi = \mu \circ \phi_0$ for $\mu : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$, so that the following holds :

1. $\phi$ has values in a ball of radius $\varepsilon$
2. $\phi$ is a short immersion

By Nash theorem you then have an approximating isometric embeding $\psi$ such that $\vert \psi - \phi \vert < \varepsilon $.

Then $\psi$ lies in a ball of radius $2 \varepsilon$.

Comment: That works only if you know embedding is bounded. This holds if manifold is compact but not necessarily if not.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ shrinks to any (open) ball of same dimension, so indeed a skrink in the shape $\mu \phi_0$ may not be sufficient. Edited.

Comment: Ah, yes. I stand corrected.

Comment: So you claim it's using the strong version of the WET?

Comment: You also need to choose your shinking map $\mu$ such that $\psi$ is short in order for the Nash-Kuiper theorem to apply, correct?

Comment: yes, sorry that's what I meant for second condition. Yes, use Whitney strong theorem to show that an map $M \to \mathbb R^n$ exists and use $\mu$ to make a function that satisfies Nash's hypothesis and apply the theorem.